# Image overlays: How to force the text within an overlaid <figcaption> to respect the boundaries of a round image?

Tags: css, text, overlay, shapes, clipping

I've checked some resources on Google regarding image overlays, but none of them answer my question which is related to **the text** inside a `figcaption` that is overlaid on a round image.

Both the `img` and the `figcaption` are rounded using `border-radius` set to `50%`.

The `figcaption` is overlaid on the image, and contains a headline and a short paragraph.

You can see my pen: http://codepen.io/cornishninja/pen/wFqrn

Hover over the image, and you'll see the text inside the `figcaption` is not clipped to the shape of the image.

Is there a way of getting the text to respect the boundaries of the circle, preferably using just CSS?

**EDIT: Since there doesn't seem to be a simple way of getting the text to follow the curve of the circle, I've resorted to using `margin`, `padding` and `text-align` to get an acceptable result. Hopefully there will be a CSS module in the future that can achieve similar results to what we could achieve in Photoshop, using shape layers and the text tool.**

Comment: Shame. I hoped there was a CSS module that covered that type of thing. I can achieve an acceptable results using text-align, padding, margin, etc but I was kinda hoping for something similar to what you could achieve in Photoshop using shape layers and the text tool.

Comment: Maybe this website will be of help. [Curvelicious](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/curvelicious/demo.html)

Comment: Thanks. I also found this tool: http://www.csstextwrap.com/index.php if anyone needs something like this.